# importing python script's methods from other python scripts in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have one program on the /Desktop called hello.py

```
 def pri():
        print "hello"
```

Then I have another program on the /Desktop called run.py

```
from hello.py import pri 

pri()
```

It gives me error that no module exist.

How can I successfully import methods from other python programs in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply call it `hello` not `hello.py`:

```
from hello import pri 
pri()
```

If you have a file called `some_name.py`, the **module** name is only `some_name` and **not** `some_name.py`.

To import all methods, do it as:

```
from hello import *
```

Comment: lol, I think I answered his question in like 2 seconds! It's nuts how fast people can answer on this site.

Comment: thanks. and how can i import all the methods of the hello.py (assuming it has more than one method)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.py`:

```
from hello import pri
          ^
```

You don't need the file extension when importing modules, so when you try to include it it will throw an error.

Comment: thanks. and how can i import all the methods of the hello.py (assuming it has more than one method)

Comment: @user3526694 That would be just `from hello import *`

Comment: @user3526694 Also if I have resolved your issue, please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). In about 4 minutes time.